# Getting filename from React fetch call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, fetch-api, filenames

I am doing a `fetch` method in React and It returns `.pdf` file that also is named and now I would like to get that filename.

```
function downloadPdf() {
    fetch(BASE_URL + `/example/example/pdf/${exampleId}`)
      .then(r => r.blob())
      .then(showFile);
}

function showFile(blob, filename) {...}
```

How can I get the filename and call my function `showFile` with the filename?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up using this instead.

```
fetch(BASE_URL + `/example/example/pdf/${exampleId}`)
  .then(response => {
      const filename =  response.headers.get('Content-Disposition').split('filename=')[1];
      response.blob().then(blob => {
        let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        let a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = url;
        a.download = filename;
        a.click();
      });
    });
```

The main problem I had here is that I forgot to expose `Content-Disposition`  in my backend API which is why the `React` couldn't read the `Content-Disposition` and that gave me a lot of headache.

Answer (score 1):

That blob should contain the file name also. 
You can get the name like this:

```js
function downloadPdf() {
    fetch(BASE_URL + `/example/example/pdf/${exampleId}`)
      .then(r => r.blob())
      .then(showFile(r));
}

function showFile(fileReceived) {
  let filename = fileReceived[0].filename;
  // other operations
}
```

Comment: I get this error : `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'filename' of undefined`. But when I look at the file in the Network inspection tab, I can still clearly see that it is there. `attachment; filename=myfileName.pdf`

Comment: Actually this solution might have worked because I hadn't exposed `Content-Disposition` before.